# programar Script de Python con Windows

Tags: python, windows

Muy buenas, tengo un código de Python que funciona correctamente si lo ejecuto yo mismo, pero si lo ejecuto como una tarea programada de Windows no obtengo ninguna respuesta, he configurado todo correctamente como aparece en otras preguntas hechas anteriormente en este foro y en el foro de habla inglesa, pero sigo sin respuesta, da igual que lo compile en un .exe o lo ejecute como .py, no realiza nada.

El script es sencillo, pero arroja un archivo txt y manda un mensaje de Telegram, quizás esa es la cuestión por lo que no funciona.

He visto todas las preguntas relacionadas con este tema pero sigo sin solucionarlo, quizás alguien sepa cual es el problema, o le haya pasado anteriormente.

Aquí va mi código:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



def func():
    url= "miUrl.com"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

    links_nuevos = []

    add='miUrl.com/asg/'

    with open("archivo.txt", "a+") as archivo:
        archivo.seek(0)
        file_links = set(archivo)

        for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('/algo/')):
            full = f"{add}{link.get('href')}\n"
            if full not in file_links:
                archivo.write(full)
                links_nuevos.append(full)
        archivo.close()

    links_nuevos2='\n'.join(links_nuevos)


    def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

        bot_token = '*****'
        bot_chatID = '*****'
        send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

        response = requests.get(send_text)

        return response.json()


    message = telegram_bot_sendtext(links_nuevos2)

Func()
```

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 punto 2 especialmente. Saludos :D

Comment: ¿Se te ha olvidado la llamada a la función `func()`?

Comment: Yo que tú coloco un par de prints estratégicamente ubicados para saber qué se ejecuta y qué no. Simple pero efectivo.

Comment: Por alguna razón el func() lo borré en mi pregunta pero está en el código original, ya está editado, añadiré varios print(), no obstante, si lo ejecuto manualmente funciona pero en el programador de tareas no, no sé de que manera me ayudarán los print()

Comment: volviendo a los prints estratégicos que sugirió @SergioR.. intenta poner uno luego de definir  `links_nuevos2`. El problema puede ser que estás abriendo un .txt ubicado en el mismo lugar que está tu script. De ser así intenta colocar el nombre completo de la ruta de tu archivo .txt

Comment: Por fin! muchas gracias @LucasDamian, efectivamente, la ruta era el problema, al no marcarle la ruta entera de mi .txt no sabia donde se encontraba el archivo en cuestión, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estaba teniendo un problema similar, en mi caso era con la biblioteca de twilio (biblioteca para envío sms).

En la tarea programada al darle "iniciar" de forma manual para ver que pasaba, se veía por medio segundo la pantalla "cmd" pero no se podía leer, entonces creé un script ".bat" de esta manera: Primero el directorio de python, espacio, después el directorio de mi script:

*"C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" "G:\scripts\traspass\traspass.py"*

*pause*

De esta manera obtuve el error. Dentro de mi script tenía el directorio de mi archivo ".json" de esta manera: "**with open('src/db.json**') as file", ya que la carpeta "src" lo tenía en la raíz del proyecto, pero al ejecutar como tarea programada no me detectaba el directorio.
Así que lo ajusté a "**with open('g:/scripts/traspass/src/db.json**') as file"

Saludos...